# How do I list out all the instances of a subclass?

Tags: python

So I'm looking for a way to list out all the instances of a subclass either through a regular method or a classmethod.
For example:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self,role, abilities, visiting, unique,Type)
        self.role = role
        self.abilities = abilities
        self.unique = unique
        self.visiting = visiting
        self.Type= Type

class Town(Player):
    def __init__(self,role,abilities,visiting,unique,Type):
        super().__init__(role,abilities,visiting,unique,Type)

Bodyguard= Town('Bodyguard', 'Choose someone to protect','Yes','No', 'Town Protective')
Crusader = Town('Crusader','Protect someone each night','Yes','No','Town Protective')
         .
         .
         .
```

I want to be able to group up all the `Type='Town Protective'` and print out a list of them. for example

```
print(Town_Protectives)
```

Displays:

```
['Bodyguard','Crusader'....]
```

This is just a little project used to help me learn Python so it's nothing serious. Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: There isn't a way to do this automatically.  Whenever you create an instance, add it to a list manually.

Comment: was your intention that `Bodyguard` and `Crusader` are instances of a class or that they are classes created on-the-fly (if you're intending to have lots of `Bodyguard`s being created, they are their own class)?  Is `Town` supposed to be a collection of `Players`?

Comment: Bodyguard and Crusader are instances of the subclass Town, and no there will only be 1 Bodyguard instance and yes Town is a collection of players so there would be sub classes like i.e: Town,Mafia,Neutral Evils...

Answer (score 2):

```
Bodyguard= Town('Bodyguard', 'Choose someone to protect','Yes','No', 'Town Protective')
Crusader = Town('Crusader','Protect someone each night','Yes','No','Town Protective')
Town_Protectives = [Bodyguard,Crusader]
print([p.role for p in Town_Protectives if p.Type == 'Town Protective'])
```

Comment: I really don't think explicitly creating a list of the instances answers this question.

Answer (score 0):

One clean way to do that is to have a class-attribute that will keep an explicit reference to each object created on that class, and then either accessing that straight, or having a classmethod to filter the isntances you want.

```
class Player:

    _register = []

    def __init__(self,role, abilities, visiting, unique,Type)
        self.role = role
        self.abilities = abilities
        self.unique = unique
        self.visiting = visiting
        self.Type= Type
        self.__class__._register.append(self) # the ".__class__." is not strictly needed;

    @classmethod
    def list(cls, Type=None):
        results = []
        for instance in self._results:
             if isinstance(instance, cls) and (Type is None or Type == instance.Type):
              results.append(instance)
        return results
```